# Home loan for plot owned by my father

Tags: loans, home

My father owns a plot, I want to build house on that land.
Land is Corporation approved and all municipal corporation procedures have been followed and plan has been sanctioned for building the house.
Father is retired govt. employee. I am Professional Govt. employee. Being a single child of my parents ,  I want to take up loan from bank. But bank is denying to provide loan to me. What can be the solution?

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Please add a country tag.

Answer (score 6):

The bank doesn't want to loan you money to build a house on property you don't own. What happens if the owner gets mad at you and wants you to leave? What happens if the owner's will gives the land to somebody else?

The bank would be taking a big risk. You need to buy the land before building the house.